# Cant adjust time in jQuery Cycle Plugin

Tags: jquery, timeout, jquery-cycle

I am building a site for client using bought HTML theme.I am almost finished, but i cant change timeout in Jquery cycle plugin that is used on the homepage.On their site i saw that i need to change timeout, but when i lower it to 3000 miliseconds, nothing happens...This is the last part of code where i believe changes should be made:

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults = {
    animIn:        {},
    animOut:       {},
    fx:           'fade',
    after:         null, 
    before:        null, 
    cssBefore:     {},
    cssAfter:      {},
    delay:         0,    
    fit:           0,    
    height:       'auto',
    metaAttr:     'cycle',
    next:          null, 
    pause:         0,    
    prev:          null, 
    speed:         1000, 
    slideExpr:     null,
    sync:          1,    
    timeout:       4000 
};
```

Comment: where are you changing timeout? don't touch code in plugin..pass it as option when you initiate cycle

Answer (score 2):

Instead of altering the source of the plugin, you should just be passing these options in when you initialize the plugin:

```
$('#my-cycle-container').cycle({
    timeout : 3000
});
```

Here is a random page from the jQuery Cycle plugin documentation: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager6.html. Notice how they passed options into the initialization of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for help, can i ask just one more thing.
In HTML, JS code is linked in <head>, but i dont see any option in the HTML like you wrote...
I only see this:

          <ul>  <li> <img src="images/1.jpg" width="940" height="350" alt="" /></li>  
            <li> <img src="images/2.jpg" width="940" height="350" alt="" /> </li> 
            <li> <img src="images/3.jpg" width="940" height="350" alt="" /></li>   
      </ul>

Comment: @Mariola That's not my demo, it's from the jQuery Cycle Plugin's documentation. You pass options in via JavaScript, like my code above.

Comment: Okay Jasper, sorry for bothering you :) Thanks!